# Use regex to capture numbers only if they don't have quotes around

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm a regex newbie in a rather weird -for me- situation. I'm trying to match all single-digit numbers (specifically 1-9, I don't need the zero) that are NOT inside quotes.

For example let's say I have the following string: `"1" or 1 ?`

I need to match `1` but NOT `"1"`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain this in Python:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('(?<!"|\d)\d(?!"|\d)')
print(pattern.findall('1,"2",34,5'))
# ['1', '5']
```

The crucial parts of this regex (`(?<!"|\d)\d(?!"|\d)`) are the negative lookahead (`?!`) and negative lookbehind (`?<!`). they are both used to prevent the regex engine to match fixed length strings.

More explanation can be found at: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Thank you so much!